Obtener el texto de una <option> de un SELECT
En Typescript, ¿Cómo puedo obtener el texto de una "option" de un SELECT? Por ejemplo, "azul".
<form [formGroup]="colors" (ngSubmit)="onSave()">
   <select class="form-select" formControlName="myList" >
      <option value="1">rojo</option>
      <option value="2">azul</option>
      <option value="3">verde</option>
   </select>

   <button type="button" (click)="onSave()"   . . .
</form>

He intentado esto en my_colors.component.ts, pero no funciona:
onSave(): void{

   console.log (this.colors.value,"VALUE SELECTED");   //Esto es ok (por ejemplo '2')

   console.log (this.colors.value.myList.selectedOptions,"TEXT SELECTED");   //Error)

}


Realmente no acabo de entender qué quieres conseguir: la lista de opciones del select deberías tenerla en el componente, lo normal es generarla en la plantilla con una lista de valores definida u obtenida ahí. ¿Puedes añadir el código del componente a la pregunta?

La lista en el html es un ejemplo. Y la pregunta creo que está clara. Lo que quiero conseguir es el texto, y no el valor.

Define las opciones en el componente y usar un *ngFor para iterar sobre ellas y mostrarlas.

@Telerin: si el texto está en la plantilla del componente, crea una lista en el componente con ese mismo texto. Por eso digo que no entiendo lo que quieres conseguir, es un texto que ya tienes

Vale, he seguido vuestros consejos y he resuelto el problema. Muchas gracias a los dos. @PabloLozano
